# Passing the useReducer dispatch down as a prop in typescript, what type to use?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

```js
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

return (
<Component dispatch={dispatch} />
)

// component file
const Component = ({dispatch}: ???) => .....
```

What should I put at the question marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`@types/react`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts). We can see that there are several overloaded definitions of `useReducer`, but it will return the type Dispatch: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L876

You can import `Dispatch` from `'react'`.

Note that `Dispatch` is generic. The generic type represents possible values for dispatched actions. It's up to you to define these, but reducers commonly use `action.type`.

```
import { Dispatch, FunctionComponent } from 'react';

interface ComponentProps {
  dispatch: Dispatch<{ type: string }>
}

const Component: FunctionComponent<ComponentProps> = ({ dispatch }) =>
```

Comment: Cheers man! Exactly what I was looking for :)